# IOError with relative path in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have this simple code

```
def main():
    ff = open("../text_learning/test_email.txt", "r")
```

when I try to run it in Visual Studio code I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../text_learning/test_email.txt'
```

But when I run it from cmd it works.

Any idea why the Visual Studio code is causing troubles?

The dir tree:

```
└───ud120-projects
    ├───.vscode
    ├───choose_your_own
    ├───datasets_questions
    ├───decision_tree
    ├───evaluation
    ├───feature_selection
    ├───final_project
    │   └───emails_by_address
    ├───k_means
    ├───naive_bayes
    ├───outliers
    ├───pca
    ├───regression
    ├───svm
    ├───text_learning
    ├───tools
    └───validation
```

The Visual Studio code is opened to the root directory (`ud120-projects`).

Comment: Try removing the ../

Comment: maybe try to make it relative to the module using `os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: Thank you guys, Wright its worked. im still learning python so sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 1):

Just change the path to

```
open("text_learning/test_email.txt", "r")
```

instead of

```
open("../text_learning/test_email.txt", "r")
```